# Ignoring stylesheet rules for part of an HTML document

Tags: html, css

I have a viewer tab which shows a complete HTML document fetched from the server. The application has a css[`main.css`] which is applied to all the elements on the screen.
If we apply this to the HTML document shown in the viewer then we loose some formatting like the table border disappears. So we do not want the application's `main.css`
to be applied to the viewer content. We want to show the document as is.
I see CDATA can be used to do this . The content inside the viewer is wrapped under `<div class="ap-mainPanel ap-scrollPanel">` so I want to escape all the content inside
the `<div class="ap-mainPanel ap-scrollPanel">` from being rendered using `main.css`

```
    <![CDATA[
        <div class="ap-mainPanel ap-scrollPanel">
        </div>
    ]]>
```

Not sure how do we specify that we want everything inside the `<div class="ap-mainPanel ap-scrollPanel">` to be escaped from applying the `main.css`

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 main options:

1. show that tab in `<iframe>` - as it not accepts parent document
   styles
2. re-apply in `main.css` rules that will clear content's in
   `.ap-mainPanel`, kind of "css reset"
3. or predefine already defined rules in `main.css` to not be applied
   in your panel ([not() pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not))

Answer (score 0):

You cannot exclude CSS from a part of an HTML document. This has been asked several times at SO, unfortunately mostly with wrong answers given.

If you use a style sheet for a page, or set of pages, you need to design it so that it actually does just what you want. This may require considerably more complicated selectors than you are currently using.

Alternatively, you can display the content as a separate document, as embedded into your main document using `iframe` (or `frame` or `object`, but `iframe` is usually the most handy). A document displayed in an `iframe` is rendered independently: only its own style sheets affect the rendering, not the “hosting” document (except that the “hosting document” sets the size of the rendering area and its position).

`CDATA` sections have nothing to do with this. They disable HTML parsing rules, turning markup to plain text. You don’t want that here.